# C# .NET BitConverter doesn't work for SQL Server stored VarBinary read

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

We're storing an integer in our SQL Server 2008 database as a `VARBINARY`. Using Entity Framework, when reading this `VARBINARY` value, it returns, to the C# code, a byte array.

Yes. I know it doesn't necessarily make sense to store the integer as a `VARBINARY` in the database right off. There is a good reason for this storage method.

Hence, the integer value of 10762007 would actually be 0xA43717 if you examined the table with a `SELECT` statement. The actual value we get in our code after reading it into a byte array is:

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{0, 164, 55, 23};
```

Now, the uninitiated might think that a simple conversion back to an integer would be:

```
int myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(b);
```

...which does not produce the desired results.

I figured this problem out by doing the following:

```
string bitString = string.Empty;
string[] bitArray = new string[4];

for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   bitArray[i] = Convert.ToString((int)b[i],2).PadLeft(8,"0");
   bitString += bitArray[i];
}

int theRealInt = Convert.ToInt32(bitString,2);
```

Which is essentially taking my integer representation of the hex values, converting them to a bit string, appending them appropriately, and then converting the big, giant bit string back to an integer.

This works but it seems like I'm doing more work than I need to. Is there some easier way to perform this action? Basically, we're storing an integer as a `VARBINARY` in the database, and then wanting to convert this back to the same integer in C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try

```
var myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(b.Reverse().ToArray(),0);
```

or

```
var myInt = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(b,0));
```

It is about [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Although it works nicely, I've never been to keen on the misappropriation of `NetworkToHostOrder`.

Comment: Thanks. This is terrific.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet has a drop-in replacement for BitConverter (`MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter`) that deals with [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues, and it can be found in the [Miscellaneous Utility Library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)